# Avoid download popup in Internet Explorer when loading file with new format in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer

In my rails app, I've defined a new format called 'extension'. My extension format is responsible for rendering views for an external web browser extension that I've developed. So I can call

/messages/new.extension

and have code specific to my web browser extension rendered.

This strategy works great until IE comes into play. On any IE version before 9, the browser doesn't know what to do with .extension files, and so IE defaults to a download popup like so:

[image]

Any thoughts on how avoid this download popup? Is there maybe another format I can use instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using:

> render :file => "#{path_to...}/messages/new.extension" :content_type => "text/html", status:
>   :ok

or

> render :text => @my_var :content_type => "text/html", status:
>   :ok